# How do I Remove an entry which is more than 30 seconds old And has null value

Tags: sql, t-sql, datetime

Objective:
`Remove all` entries `where` `LastLogin` is `null` `AND` `RegDate` is older than 30 seconds.

I'm trying to use transact SQL to remove an entry from table 'ONE'

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.ONE
WHERE LastLogin == Null AND RegDate is older than DATETIME.NOW by 30 seconds;
```

I hope the question makes sense. So how would I achieve this?

Comment: `DATEDIFF()` for working out the age, `DELETE FROM` to delete and use `IS NULL` not `= NULL`

Comment: SELECT * DELETE FROM dbo.One WHERE LastLogin IS NULL AND ... - like this?

Comment: I'd caution against deleting data unless you can guarantee that referrential integrity can be maintained.  I'd do an update instead where some column (Preferrably IsActive or EffectiveEndDate) is flagged as 'disabled' or 'inactive'.

Comment: @EastOfJupiter I  seroiusly doubt a table that records logins even has a PK let a lone a FK to another table.   Pretty sure they reserved a RegDate and then the login just did not complete.

Comment: I had assumed that this was a registered users table - where the PK is the UserID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Alex K. pointed out check for null and using datediff

```
select * from dbo.ONE where LastLogin is NULL and  
                            datediff(ss,regdate,GetDate())<30
```

Comment: This works perfectly, change from SELECT * to DELETE FROM.

Comment: Hmm doesn't work on this date : 2016-05-04 14:38:12.857 , my time now is 2016-05-04 15:44...

Comment: I hope you changed more than select to delete as < 30 is going to delete rows less than 30 seconds.

Comment: Maybe i misunderstood, replace < with  > if you want to clear out records older than 30 seconds from current time

Comment: You may want to consider making the `WHERE` clause [SARGABLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) so that it can benefit from indexes. Rather than calculating a value for each row, compare the row values to a single calculated value: `RegDate < DateAdd( second, -30, GetDate() )`. (Trivia: Curiously `GetDate()` is treated as a [runtime constant function](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/conor_cunningham_msft/archive/2010/04/23/conor-vs-runtime-constant-functions.aspx) within a query.)

Answer (score 2):

Im not 100% sure about the older part you mean `<` or `>` . But should be something like this.

```
DELETE FROM dbo.ONE
WHERE LastLogin IS NULL
  AND RegDate < DATEADD(ss, -30, getdate());
```

getdate() is current time

Comment: It returns the right rows for IS NULL but if I include the time difference check then it returns nothing. And the date is 2016-05-04 14:48:46.643 which is older than 30 seconds.

Comment: Worth noting, that (so far) this is the only solution that uses a [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) predicate (i.e. could make use of an index on `RegDate`), so I am surprised that it hasn't had more upvotes, and I can't see any issue with the `DATEADD` part - it works fine in my test: `SELECT * FROM (VALUES (1, CONVERT(DATETIME2, '2016-05-04 14:48:46.643')), (2, SYSDATETIME())) t (ID, DT) WHERE DT < DATEADD(SS, -30, GETDATE())`

Comment: Try `select DATEADD(ss, -30, getdate());` and see what result you get. Also as @GerethD say using `DATEADD` you create a constant value once and compare against `RegDate` very fast using the index. Using `DATEDIFF` you have to perform that function to every row and cant use index.

Comment: I just realize maybe you need `>` instead of `<` As I put on my answer not sure which one you mean. But in that case you question should be `delete less than 30 sec ago`

Answer (score 2):

```
DELETE FROM dbo.ONE WHERE LastLogin  IS NULL AND  datediff(second, RegDate,GetDate()) > 30;
```